# How exactly should the Hand and Foot bones be placed? (Rigify)

Tags: rigging

I added Armature to a human model with the Rigify plugin. I can easily adjust the positions of the bones. However, I am undecided about the positions and scales of the hand and foot bones. When placing the hand and foot bones on the model, should I be very sensitive to each bone piece ?

[image: hand screenshot - side]

[image: hand screenshot - top]

[image: full body screenshot - top]

[image: foot screenshot - side]

[image: feet screenshot - front]

[image: feet screenshot - front above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigify has a [Bone Positioning Guide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/bone_positioning.html) that is a good but too simple introduction to where to place the bones.

The important things for fingers is that

- The bone should initially be placed so that its ends are at the centers of the joints. As pointed out in a comment, you may have to experiment with the positions, but using the centers as a starting point will give you the start to developing the experience you need to eventually do perfect placement.
- The bone should be oriented so that the axis angles are consistent.  This is accomplished by adjusting the bone roll and adopting a rule for how the x and z axis are used.   A common rule for hands is to always orient the bone so that rotating on the X axis would match the natural rotation of the joint.

Comment: By "The bone should be oriented so that the axis angles are inconsistent," did you mean consistent? Shouldn't it be that the axes are always pointing in the same directions relative to the pointing direction of the finger?

Comment: Yes, I meant consistent.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I'll fix it now.

Comment: In my experience, the center isn't always the best position, but at the end of the day: you can't tell before you either have tried it or have enough experience to be able to predict how your mesh will deform. So focus mainly on the bones orientation and do some tests with the bones head positions. And keep in mind that, at the end of the day, bones only rotate vertices around. It will not be enough to have perfect deformations, you will need some corrective shapekeys as well.

Comment: @L0Lock  I agree that the center isn't always best. I don't think you necessarily need corrective shapekeys, but I think that's too much information for someone who is just starting to learn bone placement.  I'll update the first point to indicate it's only a starting point.